# Remove "Windows Server" pinned apps on Server 2016

Tags: windows-server, citrix, windows-server-2016, vdi

We are in the process of upgrading our VDI from Windows 2008 R2 to Windows 2016 and I cannot seem to get the pinned "Windows Server" group from showing when new users log in to the new VDI test servers. Is there a way to get rid of this group? I've looked thru GPO but only thing I have been able to find is to remove ALL pinned applications which is not something we want.

The image below will show what group I am talking about.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSccA.png)

Answer (score 0):

To customise the start menu take a look at the PowerShell functions `Export-StartLayout` and `Import-StartLayout`. Basically you need to setup a temp machine, customise the start menu as required then export it to a xml file. You can then import this config and apply those changes to other machines/images.

This guide covers the process in more detail:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2016/03/07/windows-10-start-layout-customization/

Comment: We already have a Start Menu Layout set in GPO which is being processed correctly (You can see the Office and other icons above it). However, on a 2016 Server it always seems to add the Server icons regardless of those settings.